Calculate distances in a shape with Python
I want to calculate the min vertical distance and max horizontal distance of this image.

Like the lines.
I was trying:
_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

horizontal_distances = np.sum(binary_image==255, axis=1)
max_horizontal_distance = np.max(horizontal_distances)

vertical_distances = np.sum(binary_image==255, axis=0)
min_vertical_distance = np.min(vertical_distances)

But min_vertical_distance returns 11, which is not accurate.

Hard to tell for sure without the unaltered image. But it seems accurate to me. The term "min distance" is probably not describing accurately what you are really trying to do, tho. Not just you. I often see this error made by lot of people. For example describing an area on a map (a city, a country, an island), saying stuff like "it is 1 km wide, at the thinnest part", when, clearly, it is 0. So, you have to define more accurately what vertical distance you want, since it is obviously not the min one you really want (min is 0. 11 pixels apparently, because of aliasing)

To get the length of the orange line, your method does not work. You can compute the distribution of pixels along the 0 axis like you seems to do with np.sum(binary_image==255, axis=0), then compute the derivative (eg. np.diff). There will be 3 values close to 0 in the center. The right one is where the derivative is negative before the point and positive after that (local minimal of the function located between two local maxima). There should be only one value on this image.

pixel column sums are an invalid approach. consider left/right ends of the shape to understand where and how that fails.

one valid approach is a distance transform, with some additional considerations.

now we know what this shape means: it's a human chest! follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78775537/calculate-the-inner-contour-of-a-computed-tomography

A good answer to this question will have to take into consideration shapes that are not as ideal as the one you put in the question. What's the variation that you have in your images? It can't be that all the images are so nicely symmetric?

Is your shape always axis oriented? E.g. is the vertical and horizontal image direction always your shape directions? For that "minimum" distance: Are there always two Maxima around it? Is there always such a local minimum?

To find the minimum vertical distance, you should ignore zero distances and find the smallest non-zero value using the following code:
min_vertical_distance = np.min(vertical_distances[np.nonzero(vertical_distances)])

This method should return a min_vertical_distance of 2.

and precisely that will fail. consider the left/right ends of the shape. pixel columns will be very short, yet that isn't the place to measure. invalid approach.

IIUC, you want the length of the major and minor axis. If so, you can clip the image/mask to its bounding box then look for the confluence point (something like a Cassini Oval) :
box = np.c_[np.where(binary_image > 0)]
xmin, ymin = box.min(axis=0)
xmax, ymax = box.max(axis=0)

clip = binary_image[ymin:ymax, xmin:xmax]

def confluence(arr):
    spoints = (arr[:-1] < 0) & (arr[1:] >= 0)
    return np.where(spoints)[0][-1] + 1

major = (binary_image // 255).sum(axis=1).max()  # 301
minor = (clip[:, confluence(np.diff(clip.sum(axis=0)))] // 255).sum()  # 173

Note that if you're sure to have a summetric oval, the minor can be simplified to (clip[:, clip.shape[0] // 2] // 255).sum().
Used input :

from shapely import Point, unary_union
from skimage.draw import polygon2mask

poly = unary_union([
    Point(200, 200).buffer(100),
    Point(300, 200).buffer(100)
])

coords = np.array(poly.exterior.coords)
binary_image = polygon2mask((500, 400), coords).T.astype(int) * 255

